# I want to add PHP in the place of a message

Tags: php

> Parse error syntax error unexpected T_ECHO

I want PHP in the place of 'Your Message'

```
$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array(
  'status' => 'Your Message'
));
```

I tried this

```
$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array(
  'status' => 'echo $query;'
));
```

also I tried this, same result

```
$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array(
  'status' => echo $query;
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array( 'status' => $query ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array( 'status' => $query ));
```

`$query` is already a variable. You need not echo it, just assign it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `echo` is a PHP function to print on the screen. But here you don't want to print, you want to assign a variable `status` some value (that is stored in the variable `$query`).

```
$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array(
  'status' => $query
));
```

Here `status` will be assigned the value of `$query` and since this is inside of an array, you must not write the closing `;`